# Good advanced book on developing robust C# modules

Tags: c#

I have some experience with C#, and would like to improve my knowledge of its latest improvements. I am in the middle of reading and enjoying "Effective C#" by Bill Wagner right now. However, I would appreciate more examples, especially with lambda expressions and such.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. High quality resources are preferable, and it does not matter much if they are free or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988363) - Jon Skeet

The Second Edition is in the process of being written. It definitely has some pretty good stuff including Lamda's and `dynamic` stuff.

P.S. - No pressure Jon...

Comment: +1 for an excellent recommendation.  Great book.

Comment: Fortunately I'm actually relaxing a bit at the moment: I'm waiting for chapters to come back from layout and tech review. I've got nothing to do :) It won't last, of course...

Comment: Finally published on Jan 23, 2014 in print version. Unfortunately no kindle edition or ebook :(

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation would be [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454) - an excellent book. I have not read C# in depth , but have heard its a very good book too.